# Flutter Getx. Listening to the list in Obx error. How to fix it?

Tags: flutter, state, flutter-getx, flutter-state

I updated the list in listview with Provider in Flutter. Now I'm trying to do the same with Getx. I am getting an error. I will show the code example below. I couldn't find anything on the Internet about this. I would be very happy if you help. In advance, I express my thanks to everyone.

HomeController.dart

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  final RxList<Category> category = <Category>[].obs;
  final RxList<Post> slide = <Post>[].obs;
  final RxList<Post> posts = <Post>[].obs;

Future<void> getPost() async {
    await Service().getPost(start.value, limit).then((value) {
      if (value.isNotEmpty) {
        if (value.length < limit) {
          netStatus.value = 3;
          isLoading.value = false;
        } else {
          isLoading.value = true;
        }
        posts.addAll(value);
        start.value += limit;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Post.dart  -  **This Method works very well with Provider, I want to wrap it with Obx at Getx to listen to it**

```
List<Widget> post(BuildContext context) {
  final CacheManager cacheManager = CacheService().cacheManager;
  HomeController controller = Get.find<HomeController>();

  List<Widget> posts = [
    ...controller.posts.map((post) => postCard(
          context,
          post,
          controller.category[int.parse(post.categoryId!) - 1],
          cacheManager,
        )),
  ];

  return posts;
}
```

Home.dart

```
class Home extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgets = [
      Obx(() => slider()), //**Slider works with Obx very well**
      ...post(context), /***My problem starts here. I need to
 wrap it with Obx to listen to the contents of the list.
 I can wrap the slider widget, but I can't wrap the post.
 This is required for lazyloading in Listview. 
Otherwise, all the elements are loaded without going down.***/
    ];

    return Obx(() {
      if (controller.posts.isEmpty) {
        return loadHelper(context, controller.netStatus.value, () {
          controller.getCategory();
        });
      } else {
        return RefreshIndicator(
            edgeOffset: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
            onRefresh: () => controller.onRefresh(),
            child: Obx(
              () => ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                controller: controller.scrollController,
                itemCount: widgets.length + 1,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index < widgets.length) {
                    return Obx(() => widgets[index]);
                  } else {
                    return loadHelper(context, controller.netStatus.value, () {
                      controller.getSlide();
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
            ));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Please help me solve the problem. Thank you all.**

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your attention. I watched the video. Which state manager do you think I should use? What is the best state manager for small and large projects?

Comment: My personal favorite is RiverPod.  Light on the boilerplate, but extremely versatile.  Supports multiple fan-in and fan-out for dependency steps.  Can act as a locator to swap out features for testing and mocking.  Thoroughly tested, large community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the creation of the widget list to inside the Obx, so like

```
class Home extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      List<Widget> widgets = [
        Obx(() => slider()),
        ...post(context)
      ];
      if (controller.posts.isEmpty) {
        return loadHelper(context, controller.netStatus.value, () {
          controller.getCategory();
        });
      } else {
        return RefreshIndicator(
            edgeOffset: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
            onRefresh: () => controller.onRefresh(),
            child: Obx(
              () => ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                controller: controller.scrollController,
                itemCount: widgets.length + 1,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index < widgets.length) {
                    return Obx(() => widgets[index]);
                  } else {
                    return loadHelper(context, controller.netStatus.value, () {
                      controller.getSlide();
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
            ));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I believe that should solve your issue

Comment: Sir, first of all thank you very much for your attention. The method you used works perfectly. I tried maybe 10-15 methods and asked this problem to ChatGPT, even he couldn't find the right method. Human intelligence is something else. Making a very simple change took care of the whole problem. I am grateful to you for this. I wish you success in your life and career.